# turn signal blinks wrong direction

Tags: electrical, vw, troubleshooting, turn-signal

I have a 2009 Jetta SportWagen TDI (Mk5).  When I turn on my right turn signal, usually the left turn signal turns on instead.  I'm pretty sure it is a problem in the lever arm.   I can consciously finesse the lever arm and ensure the correct turn signal turns on.  It makes me think there is a loose connection somewhere.

This never happens in the other direction.  When I turn on the left signal, the left signal always works as desired.

I'm new to auto maintenance, but consider myself to be both electrically and mechanically competent.

Is my intuition that this is the lever arm and not something further downstream sound?  Is it possible that this is a loose connection with the lever arm?  Is there any characteristic I should look for on the lever arm pins with a multimeter that could tell me if it is working properly or not?

Should I just order a new lever arm now?

On a related note: I hear VWs use "triple square" screws in some cases.  Will I need to buy some new screwdrivers for the steering wheel or turn signal arm removal?

Answer (score 1):

The indicator lever is probably spot on for the issue.

There appears to be a triple-square fastener which attaches the steering wheel to the column. The guy in [this video on air bag & steering wheel removal](https://youtu.be/OLIj1XS0m9M) says you can get away with using a T55 Torx head to pull the fastener. Other than that, it appears the job requires T20 & T25 Torx drivers. In [this video on actually removing the lever](https://youtu.be/h2goGEM-Zbs).